# Volume of a Cylinder Using Cylindrical Coordinates and Triple Integration

Tags: multivariable-calculus, integration, vector-analysis, spherical-coordinates

Calculate the Volume $V$ of a right circular cylinder of radius $a$ and height $h$, using cylindrical coordinates and triple integration.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE.  You will get better answers to your question if you include a bit more context.  What do you know about cylindrical coordinates?  Can you figure out the limits of integration?

Comment: No I do not know how to get limits of integration. The answer is suppose to be in terms of variables

Comment: This is the most basic cylindrical coordinates problem anyone could give you. Set it up first with numbers for $a$ and $h$, and then do the general case.

Answer (score 5):

Regarding to @Ted's comment, here is a hint. Please consider it and reflect. This is a very basic problem but can lead you to have more insights using other coordinates than Cartesian ones.

**Hint**
$$V=\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\int_{r=0}^a\int_{z=0}^hr drd\theta  dz$$

[image]