# What mathematically means: "The density in a point P of a cylinder is proportional to the distance of one of its basis"

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

---

Hello Guys. I'm trying to solve my first triple integral question. I'm now kinda stuck because I can't figure out what its text means. The question is: I have to find the mass of a cylinder that has the generic height = h and radius = r. The problem is that this exercise only provides me the information that "The density in a point P of a cylinder is proportional to the distance of one of its basis" and "it is delimited inferiorly by plane XOY"... I did not understand what the first expression actually means. Someone here can explain it to me?

Comment: I would interpret as follows. Put the cylinder on a table, one  of flat faces down. The density at height $z$ is $kz$ for some constant $k$.

Answer (score 1):

The density, or more precisely, the volumetric mass density, of a substance is its mass per unit volume. 
Density is defined as mass divided by volume
$$\rho = \frac{m}{V}$$
where $\rho$ is the density, $m$ is the mass, and $V$ is the volume.

Delimited by a plane XY, means that you looking only for $z\ge0$.
Finally, you going to integrate 
$$m=\iiint_V \rho dV
$$
where $V$ is a cylinder with $0\le z\le h$ and radius $r$,
and as @André Nicolas already explained $\rho(z)=kz$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, how about point P being proportional to one of its basis? Where can I use this information to solve the mass problem?

Comment: "proportional to the distance of one of its basis" this is exactly what $kz$ says, the other option is $ k (h-z)$ this is similar to taking the cylinder upside down which is still cylinder:)

Comment: Michael, thank you very much for your answer. But I'm really stucked in that question. What is the x and y integral limits? I know that the basis and the top are cilinders, so the formula is x^2 + y ^ 2 = r^2, but I can' t define the range for those integrals. Could you add this info to your answer please? TY again!

Comment: try to read this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/441590/volume-of-a-cylinder-using-cylindrical-coordinates-and-triple-integration